# Jupyter Notebook не позволяет открыть файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Jupyter Notebook не позволяет открыть файл (выдаётся ошибка `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`), хотя он определённо есть в текущей директории.

Скриншот:

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 2):

Плохая привычка использовать относительные пути, когда пытаетесь получить файлы из директории с программой. Лучше использовать специальные средства:

```py
import os
p = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "filename.json")
```

Таким образом можно получить полный путь до файла (гарантирует кроссплатформенность путей и все такое)

```py
os.getcwd()
```

Возвращает не директорию программы, а директорию с которой ее запустили.

Comment: спасибо, на будущее буду пользоваться. в этот раз все равно [не помогает](https://www.dropbox.com/s/olpozarais8smyy/2.jpg?dl=0) и файл нужный [есть в заданной директории](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9sffmf7iqwmscp8/3.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: все, простите за беспокойство)) 
Файла newyork_data.json действительно не было в папке. Но был 'newyork_data.json' (с кавычками в самом названии )

за спецсредство отдельное спасибо